# Change order of columns in "Manage Products" page grid

Tags: admin, magento-1, grid, column

I would like to switch the column order in the Manage Products admin grid.

Say I want to move the SKU column before the Name column. How would I go about that without installing any extensions?

Comment: This question is about M1.

Answer (score 3):

You can copy the product grid block

From
`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php`

to the `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php`

and change the columns order inside as you wish.

**Note, it's a fast solution but not the best practice. Creating a new extension is more upgrade-friendly.**

Answer (score 3):

You can use layout XML for that.

Create a file `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/local.xml` containing the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_catalog_product_index>
        <reference name="product.grid">
            <action method="addColumnsOrder">
                <columnId>sku</columnId>
                <after>entity_id</after>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_index>
</layout>
```

If you want to move other columns you can find the column ids in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid::_prepareColumns()`. The first parameter in the `$this->addColumn()` calls are the ids.

Of course, you can also create your own extension and add a custom layout XML file if you want to re-use it.